# Deleting from multiple ListViews based on selection in ListView1

Tags: vb.net, listview

So currently I have a system that when a button is pushed it adds whatever the button name is, so for example "**Tea**" in one column of a ListView, and it's price "**3.50**" in another.

I have made it also add this data to a ListView on another form and this is where the issue comes in. Currently, I have a `remove` button which when an item is selected, so "**Tea**" it will remove Tea from the ListView. This is all good but I also want it to remove the item from the second ListView as well.

**This is the code I have:**

```
  For Each i As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
        deleteitem = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text

        Select Case deleteitem
            Case "Tea"
                total3 = total3 - 3.5
                money.Text = total3
                total = total - 1
                Daily_sales.TextBox1.Text = total
                total2 = total2 - 3.5
                Daily_sales.TextBox11.Text = total2
                total4 = total4 - 4.0
                Form4.TextBox1.Text = total4

        End Select
        ListView1.Items.Remove(i)
```

So I've used a selectcase statement to determine what item is selected and what to subtract from other textboxes and this works.

How would I change or edit this to make it delete from the other ListView as well?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can put your code in a method that accepts a ListView. Then use the argument, which is a ListView, when you remove its item.